# Integrating $\int {1 \over e^x \sqrt{1-e^{-2x}}}\ dx$

Tags: calculus

I would like to receive a tip on how to start taking the antiderivative of this problem. Its from a problem where you show if its divergent, however I just want to figure out how to find the antiderivative.

Comment: $\mathrm e^{-x} \mathrm dx = \mathrm d(-\mathrm e^{-x})$, so…

Comment: *Mathematica* gives:  $\frac{e^{-x} \sqrt{e^{2 x}-1} \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{e^{2 x}-1}\right)}{\sqrt{1-e^{-2
   x}}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u=e^{-x}, du =-e^{-x}dx$ turns your integral into a well known one.

Comment: I just tried your method, and it seems like it worked. I ended up subbing in and getting -du/(sqrt(1-u^2)) --> -sin^-1 (sqrt(1-e^-2x )) + c

Comment: Very good , thanks

Answer (score 1):

Given $$\int \dfrac{1}{e^x\sqrt{1-e^{-2x}}}\ dx$$

Take u substitution $u=e^x$ and $du=e^x\ dx$
$$\int \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac1{u^2}}\ \ u^2}\ du$$
Apply $t$ substitution $t=\sqrt{1-\dfrac{1}{x^2}}$

$$=\int\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{-t^2+1}}\ dt=\arcsin\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2}-1}{x}\right)+C$$

Comment: What would you do with the e^-x or what would du be equals too?

Comment: @LukeD differentiate $u=\sqrt{1-e^{-2x}}$ and you get $du$

Comment: I'm still a bit confused on how that solves for the e^-x there. For what I get as to what du is equal too, its not e^-x.

Comment: @LukeD See the edited answer